# mutation to create relations on AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have been trying to run a mutation to create relations to two separate Types with not much success.

** SCHEMA **

(I have used "Create Resources" to create tables in DynamoDB)

```
type Comment {
    eventId: ID!
    commentId: String!
    content: String
}

type CommentConnection {
    items: [Comment]
    nextToken: String
}

input CreateCommentInput {
    eventId: ID!
    commentId: String!
    content: String
}

input CreateEventInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    where: String
    when: String
    description: String
}

input DeleteCommentInput {
    eventId: ID!
}

input DeleteEventInput {
    id: ID!
}

type Event {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    where: String
    when: String
    description: String
    comments(limit: Int, nextToken: String): CommentConnection
}

type EventConnection {
    items: [Event]
    nextToken: String
}

type Mutation {
    createEvent(input: CreateEventInput!): Event
    updateEvent(input: UpdateEventInput!): Event
    deleteEvent(input: DeleteEventInput!): Event
    createComment(input: CreateCommentInput!): Comment
    updateComment(input: UpdateCommentInput!): Comment
    deleteComment(input: DeleteCommentInput!): Comment
    commentOnEvent(input: commentOnEventInput!): Comment
}

type Query {
    fetchEvent(id: ID!): Event
    getEvent(id: ID!): Event
    listEvents(first: Int, after: String): EventConnection
    getComment(eventId: ID!): Comment
    listComments(first: Int, after: String): CommentConnection
}

type Subscription {
    onCreateEvent(
        id: ID,
        name: String,
        where: String,
        when: String,
        description: String
    ): Event
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createEvent"])
    onUpdateEvent(
        id: ID,
        name: String,
        where: String,
        when: String,
        description: String
    ): Event
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateEvent"])
    onDeleteEvent(
        id: ID,
        name: String,
        where: String,
        when: String,
        description: String
    ): Event
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteEvent"])
    onCreateComment(eventId: ID, commentId: String, content: String): Comment
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createComment"])
    onUpdateComment(eventId: ID, commentId: String, content: String): Comment
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateComment"])
    onDeleteComment(eventId: ID, commentId: String, content: String): Comment
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteComment"])
}

input UpdateCommentInput {
    eventId: ID!
    commentId: String
    content: String
}

input UpdateEventInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    where: String
    when: String
    description: String
}

input commentOnEventInput {
    eventId: ID!
    content: String
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}
```

** MUTATIONS **

mutation #1:

```
mutation {
    createEvent(input: {
    id: "id8888"
        name: "some event"
    where: "Tokyo"
        when: "tomorrow"
        description: "desc for event"
  })
  {
    id
        name
    }
}
```

mutation #1 gives:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createEvent": {
      "id": "id8888",
      "name": "some event"
    }
  }
}
```

mutation #2:

```
mutation {
  commentOnEvent(input : {
    eventId: "id8888"
    commentId: "id2222"
    content: "some content"
  })
  {
    commentId
    content
  }
}
```

mutation #2 gives:

```
{
  "data": {
    "commentOnEvent": null
  }
}
```

In the React sample created by AWS AppSync creates commentId automatically but I can't recreate that in manually created schema and resource.

I would like to know how I can establish relations on separate types and query them. Has anybody successfully done this??

Answer (score 12):

Starting from the console's “Create resources” functionality lets talk through how this works. Assume we have this schema.

```
type Comment {
    eventId: ID!
    commentId: String!
    content: String
}

type CommentConnection {
    items: [Comment]
    nextToken: String
}

input CreateCommentInput {
    eventId: ID!
    commentId: String!
    content: String
}

input CreateEventInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    where: String
    when: String
    description: String
}

input DeleteCommentInput {
    eventId: ID!
}

input DeleteEventInput {
    id: ID!
}

type Event {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    where: String
    when: String
    description: String
    comments(limit: Int, nextToken: String): CommentConnection
}

type EventConnection {
    items: [Event]
    nextToken: String
}

type Mutation {
    createEvent(input: CreateEventInput!): Event
    updateEvent(input: UpdateEventInput!): Event
    deleteEvent(input: DeleteEventInput!): Event
    createComment(input: CreateCommentInput!): Comment
    updateComment(input: UpdateCommentInput!): Comment
    deleteComment(input: DeleteCommentInput!): Comment
}

type Query {
    getEvent(id: ID!): Event
    listEvents(first: Int, after: String): EventConnection
    getComment(eventId: ID!): Comment
    listComments(first: Int, after: String): CommentConnection
}

type Subscription {
    onCreateEvent(
        id: ID,
        name: String,
        where: String,
        when: String,
        description: String
    ): Event
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createEvent"])
    onUpdateEvent(
        id: ID,
        name: String,
        where: String,
        when: String,
        description: String
    ): Event
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateEvent"])
    onDeleteEvent(
        id: ID,
        name: String,
        where: String,
        when: String,
        description: String
    ): Event
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteEvent"])
    onCreateComment(eventId: ID, commentId: String, content: String): Comment
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createComment"])
    onUpdateComment(eventId: ID, commentId: String, content: String): Comment
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateComment"])
    onDeleteComment(eventId: ID, commentId: String, content: String): Comment
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteComment"])
}

input UpdateCommentInput {
    eventId: ID!
    commentId: String
    content: String
}

input UpdateEventInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    where: String
    when: String
    description: String
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}
```

This is what the schema should look like after running Create Resources on the Event and Comment types. When going through the "Create Resources" flow with the Comment type you should choose the **eventId** as the table's hash key and the **commentId** as the sort key. For the Event type you can leave "id" as the single hash key. So what did that do for us?

First it created 2 DynamoDB tables to hold our objects of type Event and Comment. It then imported those tables as AppSync data sources and generated new schema parts including input objects, objects, and query and mutation fields and saved them to the schema. It also wired up resolvers specific to the new table you just defined and attached them to the newly generated query and mutation fields that implement common CRUD patterns. Unfortunately this does not yet understand relations so we have to add those ourselves. To do that let's first make the mutation to create relations as you have asked about and for completeness we will do a query as well.

As you have already done, you are going to need to add something like this to your schema

```
type Mutation {
  commentOnEvent(input: CommentOnEventInput!): Comment
}
input CommentOnEventInput {
  eventId: ID!
  content: String
}
```

Save the schema and then click "Attach" on the **Mutation.commentOnEvent** field to add a resolver. Select the CommentTable data source we created earlier and from the mapping template put this:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
      "eventId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.eventId),
      "commentId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input)
}
```

and for the response mapping template

```
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

Click save. Now you should be able to run a query like this:

```
mutation {
  commentOnEvent(input: { eventId: "***", content: "A comment"}) {
    eventId
    content
  }
}
```

Let's now add away to read data via a relation. E.G. I want to be able to run a query like this:

```
query {
  getEvent(id: "***") {
    id
    comments(first: 5) {
      items {
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To do this lets first add the following parts to the schema.

```
type Event {
  # add this to existing fields
  comments(first: Int, after: String): CommentConnection
}
```

Click save then click "Attach" on the **Event.comments** field. Select the CommentTable data source again and then provide the following for the request mapping template.

```
# Event.comments.request.vtl
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expression": "eventId = :eventId",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":eventId" : {
                "S" : "${ctx.source.id}"
            }
        }
    },
    "limit": $util.defaultIfNull(${ctx.args.first}, 20),
    "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.args.after, null))
}
```

Notice the **$ctx.source.id**. Since we are resolving the **Event.comments** field, the **$ctx.source** is the instance of the Event type that we are resolving comments for. In effect this makes it so that anywhere we include `{ comments { ... }` in a selection set on the **Event** type, only comments for the parent event will be fetched. And then you can return the paginated result object.

```
# Event.comments.response.vtl
# $ctx.result = { items: [...], nextToken: "..." }
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

This should do the trick. Now you can run both these queries and see the results.

```
mutation {
  commentOnEvent(input: { eventId: "***", content: "A comment"}) {
    eventId
    content
  }
}


query {
  getEvent(id: "***") {
    id
    comments(first: 5) {
      items {
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for detailed instruction, trying line by line

After setting up comment table with resolver to set commentId with autoId(), mutation like this doesn't create another row in comment table and overwrites an old one with "id2222"

`mutation
{ commentOnEvent(input: {
eventId: "id2222",
content: "something else comment"})
{eventId
content } 
}`

Comment: and query like below gives me an error

`query {
  getEvent(id: "id2222") {
    id
    comments(first: 5) {
      items {
        content
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I'm going to need more information to help debug this. If you have the resolver template above and a table with a HASH key of "eventId" and a SORT key of "commentId" then a new row will be created. I'd double check that you have everything configured correctly. I have this working on my end.

Comment: It would be great if you wrote a blog post about this. There is not a lot of information about relations and AppSync, not even in the docs.

Comment: @Pier I just might. Here are some new

Comment: Sorry clicked enter too early. I was going to say, here are some new docs on creating relationships in AppSync using AWS Amplify and the GraphQL transforms @model directive: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/graphql#connection

Comment: Is it possible to use those @ notations in the regular AppSync schema without Amplify?

Comment: No it's only usable from amplify. The directives are compiled into resolver templates when you build the Amplify project.