# Circular refrence AWS appsync

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I want to know if having a circular reference in AWS Appsync possible or not? I have searched a lot but couldn't find it. Something like this:

```
type Post {
    title: String!
    content: String!
    user: User!
}

type Query {
    allPosts: [Post!]
    singlePost(id: String!): Post!
}

type User {
    name: String!
    posts: [Post!]
}
```

### Edit (Tried lambda with the logic described here https://youtu.be/bgq7FRSPDpI?list=PL55RiY5tL51rG1x02Yyj93iypUuHYXcB_&t=526 )

Here's the lambda resolver for allPosts (handler function will be called):

```
import * as sdk from "aws-sdk";

declare var process: {
  env: {
    TABLE_NAME: string;
  };
};

interface Event {
  info: {
    fieldName: string;
    parentTypeName: string;
    variables: Record<string, any>;
  };
}

const client = new sdk.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const getUser = (user_id: string): Record<string, any> | null => {
  return client
    .query({
      TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
      KeyConditionExpression: "PK = :pk AND SK = :sk",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":pk": user_id,
        ":sk": "profile",
      },
    })
    .promise()
    .then(
      (data) =>
        data.Items?.map((item) => ({
          ...item.data,
          posts: getPost.bind(null, item.PK),
        }))[0]
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    });
};

const getPost = (user_id: string): Record<string, any> | null => {
  return client
    .query({
      TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
      KeyConditionExpression: "SK = :sk AND pk = :pk",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":pk": user_id,
        ":sk": "profile",
      },
    })
    .promise()
    .then((data) =>
      data.Items?.map((item) => ({
        ...item.data,
        user: getUser.bind(null, item.PK),
      }))
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    });
};

export const handler = async (event: Event) => {
  if (event.info.fieldName === "allPosts") {
    const data = await client
      .query({
        TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
        KeyConditionExpression: "#t = :sk",
        IndexName: "GSI",
        ProjectionExpression: "#d, PK",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#t": "type",
          "#d": "data",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":sk": "post",
        },
      })
      .promise();
    const result = data.Items?.map((item) => ({
      ...item.data,
      user: getUser.bind(null, item.PK),
    }));
    console.log(data, result);
    return result;
  }
  return;
  //   else if (event.fieldName === "singlePost") {

  //   }
};
```

The user field has a function bounded as in this video: https://youtu.be/bgq7FRSPDpI?list=PL55RiY5tL51rG1x02Yyj93iypUuHYXcB_&t=526

But lambda response is not returning the bounded function.

```
[
  {
    "title": "post by user_123",
    "content": "\n\nNew to this community. I need some help in designing the Amazon Dynamo DB table for my personal projects.\n\nOverview, this is a simple photo gallery application with following attributes.\n\nUserID\nPostID\nList item\nS3URL\nCaption\nLikes\nReports\nUploadTime\nI wish to perform the following queries:\n\nFor a given user, fetch 'N' most recent posts\nFor a given user, fetch 'N' most liked posts\nGive 'N' most recent posts (Newsfeed)\nGive 'N' most liked posts (Newsfeed)\nMy solution:"
  },
  {
    "title": "another post by user_123",
    "content": "\n\nNew to this community. I need some help in designing the Amazon Dynamo DB table for my personal projects.\n\nOverview, this is a simple photo gallery application with following attributes.\n\nUserID\nPostID\nList item\nS3URL\nCaption\nLikes\nReports\nUploadTime\nI wish to perform the following queries:\n\nFor a given user, fetch 'N' most recent posts\nFor a given user, fetch 'N' most liked posts\nGive 'N' most recent posts (Newsfeed)\nGive 'N' most liked posts (Newsfeed)\nMy solution:"
  }
]
```

But I can see the bounded function in the logs:

```
[
  {
    title: 'post by user_123',
    content: '\n' +
      '\n' +
      'New to this community. I need some help in designing the Amazon Dynamo DB table for my personal projects.\n' +
      '\n' +
      'Overview, this is a simple photo gallery application with following attributes.\n' +
      '\n' +
      'UserID\n' +
      'PostID\n' +
      'List item\n' +
      'S3URL\n' +
      'Caption\n' +
      'Likes\n' +
      'Reports\n' +
      'UploadTime\n' +
      'I wish to perform the following queries:\n' +
      '\n' +
      "For a given user, fetch 'N' most recent posts\n" +
      "For a given user, fetch 'N' most liked posts\n" +
      "Give 'N' most recent posts (Newsfeed)\n" +
      "Give 'N' most liked posts (Newsfeed)\n" +
      'My solution:',
    user: [Function: bound getUser]
  },
  {
    title: 'another post by user_123',
    content: '\n' +
      '\n' +
      'New to this community. I need some help in designing the Amazon Dynamo DB table for my personal projects.\n' +
      '\n' +
      'Overview, this is a simple photo gallery application with following attributes.\n' +
      '\n' +
      'UserID\n' +
      'PostID\n' +
      'List item\n' +
      'S3URL\n' +
      'Caption\n' +
      'Likes\n' +
      'Reports\n' +
      'UploadTime\n' +
      'I wish to perform the following queries:\n' +
      '\n' +
      "For a given user, fetch 'N' most recent posts\n" +
      "For a given user, fetch 'N' most liked posts\n" +
      "Give 'N' most recent posts (Newsfeed)\n" +
      "Give 'N' most liked posts (Newsfeed)\n" +
      'My solution:',
    user: [Function: bound getUser]
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Try doing it and see what happens

Comment: I tried binding functions for user in Post type in lambda (JavaScript). Seems not to be working. Let me add the code here

Comment: Take 5 minutes to *please* take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question to help us help you :)

Comment: I have added details.

Comment: Much better, please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344!

Comment: I have added text logs in place of images, but don't know why syntax is not highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes, appsync can easily handle nested or "circular" queries.  The key insight is that it's not the `allPosts` handler's job to resolve the `User` type behind the `user` field.  Instead, appsync will invoke the lambda resolver *a second time* to get the `user` field's `User`.  We need to add branching logic in our lambda to handle the second invocation, where `event.info.fieldName === "user"`.

```js
// a switch statement inside your lambda function handler "routes" the request

switch (event.parentTypeName) {
  case "Query":
    switch (event.fieldName) {
      case "allPosts":
        // depends on your schema
        const userID = event.arguments?.["id"]
        // handle query, return [Post!], as per your schema
      case "singlePost"
        const postID = event.arguments?["id"]
        // ditto, return Post!, as per your schema
    }
  case "Post":
    switch (event.fieldName) {
      case "user":
       // event.source is a Post, details depend on your actual schema
       const userID = event.source?.["userID"]
       // make dynamo call to get the User and return a User, type that your graphql schema is expecting
    }
  case "User":
    switch (event.fieldName) {
      case "posts":
         // event.source is a User, details depend on your actual schema
        const userID = event.source?.["id"]
        // fetch posts from dynamo, return [Post!], the type your graphql schema is expecting
    }
  default:
    throw new Error("unhandled parent type")
}
```

**Context**:  this answer, like the question, assumes our datasource is a [direct lambda resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-direct-lambda/), meaning our function receives as an arg the [full context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html) and that we don't use VTL templates.  It also assumes the general default choice of having a single lambda resolver with a giant `switch` statement to handle the various incoming requests.

**Resolvable Fields are resolved separately by appsync.**  A resolvable field has a resolver datasource. In our case, it is a lambda function.  For each resolvable field appsync encounters, appsync will make a separate call to the resolver.  (BTW, my guess is that you have *already* configured `User` with a datasource.  That would solve the mystery of why `allPosts` is not returning user results.  Resolving users is not its job, and your lambda is not currently handling a `event.info.fieldName` of `user`).

**Setting Resolvers** aws gives us several ways to assign a resolver to a field, including in the console (schema tab, attach button) and the [cdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html#resolvable-fields) (add a [LambdaDataSource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync.LambdaDataSource.html) to a [ObjectType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync.ObjectType.html)).

**How do we get the `user` id?**  Appsync gives us the `event` arg for `user` PK/SK info for our dynamodb call. The `event` gives us lots of info, including `fieldName`, `parentTypeName`, and crucially, a `source` key with the parent field's values. `console.log` the `event` to discover what you've got to work with.

**Extra Credit**

**Q:** How many times will appsync invoke our lambda for the following query?

```
query allPosts(limit: 10) {
    title
    content
    user {
        name
    }
}
```

**A:** 11 times.  1x for `allPosts`, 10x for `user`.

**Prior Art** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342523/appsync-nested-type-resolver) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083207/returning-appsync-graphql-type-that-also-has-field-resolvers) SO post for similar answers.

**Don't try this at home** It is theoretically possible, if quite silly, to remove the `User` type resolver, thereby handing to `allPosts` (and other queries) the responsibility to return users.  Due to the potentially deep nesting of query return values, rather complicated for zero gain.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is clearly explained and very detailed. I didn't know the concept of a field resolver and this answer made this concept a piece of cake!