# AWS Graphql lambda query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-server

**I am not using AWS AppSync for this app**. I have created Graphql schema, I have made  my own resolvers. For each create, query, I have made each Lambda functions. I used DynamoDB Single table concept and it's Global secondary indexes.

It was ok for me, to create an Book item. In DynamoDB, the table looks like this: [image].

I am having issue with the return Graphql queries. After getting the `Items` from DynamoDB table, I have to use Map function then return the `Items` based on Graphql `type`. I feel like this is not efficient way to do that. Idk the best way query data. Also I am getting null both author and authors query.

This is my [gitlab-branch](https://gitlab.com/alak/aws-book-schema-graphql).

**This is my Graphql Schema**

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-lambda';

const typeDefs = gql`
  enum Genre {
    adventure
    drama
    scifi
  }

  enum Authors {
    AUTHOR
  }

  # Root Query - all the queries supported by the schema

  type Query {
    """
    All Authors query
    """
    authors(author: Authors): [Author]
    books(book: String): [Book]
  }

  # Root Mutation - all the mutations supported by the schema
  type Mutation {
    createBook(input: CreateBook!): Book
  }

  """
  One Author can have many books
  """
  type Author {
    id: ID!
    authorName: String
    book: [Book]!
  }

  """
  Book Schema
  """
  type Book {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    price: String
    publishingYear: String
    publisher: String
    author: [Author]
    description: String
    page: Int
    genre: [Genre]
  }

  input CreateBook {
    name: String
    price: String
    publishingYear: String
    publisher: String
    author: [CreateAuthor]
    description: String
    page: Int
    genre: [Genre]
  }

  input CreateAuthor {
    authorName: String!
  }
`;
export default typeDefs;
```

**This is I created the Book Item**

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';
import { CreateBook } from '../../generated/schema';

async function createBook(_: unknown, { input }: { input: CreateBook }) {
  const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const id = v4();

  const authorsName = 
    input.author &&
    input.author.map(function (item) {
      return item['authorName'];
    });

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.ITEM_TABLE ? process.env.ITEM_TABLE : '',
    Item: {
      PK: `AUTHOR`,
      SK: `AUTHORS#${id}`,
      GSI1PK: `BOOKS`,
      GSI1SK: `BOOK#${input.name}`,
      name: input.name,
      author: authorsName,
      price: input.price,
      publishingYear: input.publishingYear,
      publisher: input.publisher,
      page: input.page,
      description: input.description,
      genre: input.genre,
    },
  };

  await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();

  return {
    ...input,
    id,
  };
}

export default createBook;
```

**This is how query the All Book**

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

async function books(_: unknown, input: { book: string }) {
  const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.ITEM_TABLE ? process.env.ITEM_TABLE : '',
    IndexName: 'GSI1',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'GSI1PK = :hkey',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':hkey': `${input.book}`,
    },
  };

  const { Items } = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise();

  const allBooks =  // NEED TO MAP THE FUNcTION THEN RETURN THE DATA BASED ON GRAPHQL //QUERIES.
    Items &&
    Items.map((i) => {
      const genre = i.genre.filter((i) => i);
      return {
        name: i.name,
        author: i.author,
        genre,
      };
    });

  return allBooks;
}

export default books;
```

**This my Author query and Image of the console result**

[image]

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Author, Authors } from '../../generated/schema';

async function authors(
  _: unknown,
  input: { author: Authors }
): Promise<Author> {
  const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.ITEM_TABLE ? process.env.ITEM_TABLE : '',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :hkey',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':hkey': `${input.author}`,
    },
  };

  const { Items } = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise();

  console.log({ Items }); // I can see the data but don't know how to returns the data like this below type without using map function

  // type Author {
  //   id: ID!
  //   authorName: String
  //   book: [Book]!
  // }

  return Items; // return null in Graphql play ground. 
}

export default authors;
```

Edit: current resolver map

```js
// resolver map - src/resolvers/index.ts
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books,
    authors,
    author,
    book,
  },
  Mutation: {
    createBook,
  },
};
```

Comment: Could you help clarify what your actual question/problem is?  Is it about lambda resolver writing, like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69746090/1103511) (question is AppSync-related, Apollo Server follows similar logic)?  Perhaps give a client query example and add  what you mean by its "efficient" handling.

Comment: Question is how can I get, authors’ name and his/her/their books. I am getting null atm.

Comment: Please add your [resolver map](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#passing-resolvers-to-apollo-server) to the question.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and sticking with me . This is my branch: https://gitlab.com/alak/aws-book-schema-graphql

Comment: Both Author and Authors' query I am getting null. I newbie in Graphql. If I made any mistake please feel free to give me feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** You are missing some resolvers. Your query resolvers are trying to do the job of the missing resolvers. Your resolvers must return data in the right shape.

In other words, your problems are with configuring Apollo Server's resolvers.  Nothing Lambda-specific, as far as I can tell.

##### Write and register the missing resolvers.

GraphQL doesn't know how to "resolve" an author's books, for instance. Add a `Author {books(parent)}` entry to Apollo Server's [resolver map](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#resolvers). The corresponding resolver function should return a list of book objects (i.e. `[Books]`), as your schema requires. Apollo's docs have a similar [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#example) you can adapt.

Here's a refactored `author` query, commented with the resolvers that will be called:

```
query author(id: '1') {     # Query { author } resolver
  authorName
  books {                   # Author { books(parent) } resolver
    name
    authors {               # Book { author(parent) } resolver
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Apollo Server uses the resolver map during query execution to decide what resolvers to call for a given query field.  It's not a coincidence that the map looks like your schema.  Resolver functions are called with [parent, arg, context and info](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers) arguments, which give your functions the context to fetch the right records from the data source.

```js
// resolver map - passed to the Apollo Server constructor
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books,
    authors,
    author,
    book,
  },

  Author: {
    books(parent) { getAuthorBooks(parent); }, // parent is the author - resolver should return a list of books
  },

  Book: {
    authors(parent) { getBookAuthors(parent); }, // parent is the book - resolver should return a list of authors
  },
};
```

##### Your query resolvers are trying to do too much work.

It's not the author query resolver's job to resolve all the child fields. Apollo Server will call multiple resolvers multiple times [during query execution](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/):

> You can think of each field in a GraphQL query as a function or method of the previous type which returns the next type. In fact, this is exactly how GraphQL works. Each field on each type is backed by a function called the resolver which is provided by the GraphQL server developer. When a field is executed, the corresponding resolver is called to produce the next value

Apollo Server calls this the [resolver chain](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-chains). The `books(parent)` resolver will be invoked with `Author` as its `parent` argument. You can use the author id to look up her books.

##### Your resolver return values must be consistent with the schema.

Make sure your resolvers are returning data in the shape required by the schema. Your `author` resolver is apparently returning a map `{Items: [author-record]}`, but your schema says it needs to be a list.

(If I were you, I would change the author query signature from `author(PK: String, SK: String): [Author]` to something more caller-friendly like `author(id: ID): Author`. Return an Object, not a List. Hide the DynamoDB implementation details in the resolver function. Apollo Server has a `ID` scalar type that is [serialised as a String](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/schema/#scalar-types).)

Comment: Thanks a lot @fedonev. Really neat and nice explanation.

Comment: Just one thing, how will you create “getAuthorBooks“ function?

Comment: Glad to help.   Your `src/resolvers/query` folder's `author.ts` resolver is a start.   Resolvers often make use of switch statements to handle different sources of the identifying data in a single function - e.g. is this a request for author from the author query or the author as a child of book?