# Appsync query on relation child object

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am in the situation of [mutation to create relations on AWS AppSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319894/mutation-to-create-relations-on-aws-appsync/51331406#51331406)

I have events in one table, comments in another. In my graphql events type I have a field for list of comments with its own resolver

I would like to know how I can request only events that have comments, in the same way.

My situation makes I need also to filter which events I want to show so I can not start by getting list of distinct events in the comment table.

I would not like if it can be avoided to create a pipeline with specific resolver, to avoid code duplication.

Code can be retrieved to the linked stackoverflow question.

Thank you for help